# Meaning of "pcm"

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

I'm trying to rent an apartment and the price is written as:

> £1,000 **pcm**.

What does that mean?

Comment: for the future, you can use the [acronym finder website](http://www.acronymfinder.com/)

Comment: And browse the [104 definitions](http://www.acronymfinder.com/PCM.html) for PCM...

Comment: @dr65 they are sorted by rank and this one is the third one. Using the context, the user can figure out further which one it is.

Comment: It does say (accounting) after *PCM = per calendar month*, though.  Probably just to throw off the search.

Comment: @Richard: We're closing this not necessarily because we think *you* should have known how to find the definition of PCM; it's just that one has only to follow a few leads google can easily give us.  Hopefully you got some good tips for your future searching!

Answer (score 3):

*[Per calendar month.](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061109013754AAn3Gk9)*  There are indeed [104 meanings](http://www.acronymfinder.com/PCM.html) attached to *PCM*, but you should be able to find the right one by googling more specifically (e.g. *PCM stand for renting* or something similar).

Comment: lessons in googling

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't it make to use it to mean "per calendar month"?

Comment: per calender month being the important detail that you pay 1000*12 in a year, while per month means every 4weeks = 1000*13 in a year!

Comment: Really?  I would have thought *pcm* meant that the months are counted beginning at the first of a month, and ending on the last (e.g. Jan 1 to Feb 1); whereas *per month* would mean from any day one month to that day next month (e.g. Jan 22 to Feb 22).  Either way, there are 12 months per year.  How do you know *per month* = *per 4 weeks*, resulting in 13 "months" per year?

Comment: @drɱ65, yes PCM = on same day each month (ie 12/year), while per month 'can' mean every 4 weeks. How do you know ? Unscrupulous landlords!